# The shortest path

Tags: c++, path, shortest-path

This is my code to generate a 2-dimensional table with pseudo numbers.

when it creates a so-called square of numbers for me, e.g.

```
2 1 1 1
1 9 1 2
9 8 3 1
```

then I have to choose the shortest path from left to right and I can go down and up and diagonally and the exit is to be that the path leads through 1 1 1 1 and that the sum of half is equal to 4

And I dont know how to start writing code for the shortest path can somebody help me or give me advise how i can do it. i searched for matrix in c++ but i dont know how it need works.

```
for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < b; j++)
    {
        tab[i][j] = rand() % 9 + 1; 
        cout << tab[i][j] << " "; 
    }
    cout << endl;
}

return 0;
```

Comment: why is sum of `1 1 1 1` `3`?

Comment: note that this is special case of shortest path in a graph. As a hint see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem In your case BFS should do the job nicly.

Comment: I think it is simpler than BFS. You can create another table with information "how far you are from destination" and fill it down-top, right-left: add current value to min(right neighbor, down neighbor)